# Excel Date Timezone Conversion

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, time, date-time

I have a spreadsheet from a system that outputs the date and time format like this:

```
15/09/2021 04:29 AM
```

The format of the field/cell is Custom:

```
dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm
```

How do I convert the output so that it shows in GMT, therefore needs to show:

```
15/09/2021 09:29 AM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the time offset, you can calculate it using the `TIME` function.

Let assume compare to the time on your cell, GMT time is 8 hours ahead, use the formula:

```
=A1 + TIME(8,0,0)
```

If GMT is 8 hours behind, use the formula:

```
=A1 - TIME(8,0,0)
```

[image: Results]